# Impossible to connect to EC2 instance after mountpoint (connection refused)

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I tried three times today to reduce my EBS volume following some tutorials that I found on internet. It's a secondary volume, not the root one. Everything seems to work fine until I stop the machine and try to start it again.

Before stopping it, I mount a new smaller volume, rsync the files from one volume to another, unmount both of them and mount the new one in the good directory. When I d a lsblk, everything is perfect then I stop the instance to detach the old bigger volume and I can't start the instance anymore.

I saw many different solutions on internet for that that mainly consists on launching another instance, detaching and attaching again volumes. However, I would like to know why this happens??

The message: **ssh: connect to host myhost port 22: Connection refused**

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the comments, but yes I did umount the mountpoints and changed the /etc/fstab before creating an image of my instance. It happened to me again last week. Its is a little bit annoying.

This time, I didn't even change the mountpoints. I just wanted to make an extra backup of my instance. It seems that during the creation of the image the instance reboots and then it cannot start again.

I'm wondering if I should stop the instance before asking for an image. Do someone know the best practices to do it?

Comment: What steps did you take in the tutorials/what were the tutorials? Did the tutorials have you modify /etc/fstab so that the correct volume is mounted on reboot? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006805/automatically-mount-an-ebs-volume-upon-starting-an-amazon-ec2-linux-instance

Comment: Take a look at the System Log provided by Amazon from the AWS console to trace where in the booting process your instance gets stuck. Most surely the /etc/fstab file is referencing an old device name, happened to me tens of times.